# Divide a grid into 3 columns

Tags: html, grid, semantic-ui

I want to create something like in the image below

[image]

I have this

```
<div class="ui page grid">
    <div class="ui segment">
        <div class="sixteen wide column">
            <a class="ui green circular label"></a>
            <h5>{{this.email}}{{this.totalTimeExpire}}</h5>
            <h6>{{this.timeRemaining}} remaining</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have already tried using `sixteen wide column` and dividing it into 3 child columns, but it just doesn't work. How should my grid code look to place all the 3 columns (the green circle, username and count of time remaining) in the same inline order?

Comment: When you say something doesn't work you should explain how is not working, maybe adding a picture? So it is more clear for people to help you.

Comment: Yep my bad, let me upload the image to show what im getting with this structure

Comment: I have edited the title to explain what you are actually trying to do instead of having just the library or tag names. Titles should not be just a combination of tag or library names. I have also corrected some typo and grammar errors in the content.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure why are you using Segment element, but here is the solution:

```
<div class="ui grid container">
    <div class="left floated five wide column">
        <a class="ui green circular label"></a>
        {{this.email}}{{this.totalTimeExpire}}
    </div>
    <div class="right floated five wide column">
        {{this.timeRemaining}} remaining
    </div>
</div>
```

Use "container" instead of "page grid", and if you are working with Semantic-UI v1 just upgrade to the SUI v2 (http://beta.semantic-ui.com), it will be released Tuesday June 30th and I dont think that SUI v1 is supported anymore.

PS: "ui container" is added to SUI v2

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are asking but if you are trying to make just three columns why not wrap in a `<ul>` tag and give a style of `display:table` and
`<li>`tags with a style of `display:table-cell` , this will give you alot of flexibility when it comes to positioning the columns.

Comment: Adam, you should add your comments as comments, not as different answers. Also you can edit your own answer, don't duplicate answers. Look in your answer to the left there are three links "share", "edit" and "flag". Click on edit to modify your answer and delete the other one.

Answer (score 0):

In version 2.1, the current version as of this writing, you can now divide a grid into three columns.

```
<div class="ui three column grid">
  <div class="column">
      <a class="ui green circular label"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="ten wide column">
      {{this.email}}{{this.totalTimeExpire}}
  </div>
  <div class="five wide column">
      {{this.timeRemaining}} remaining
  </div>
</div>
```